# What is the best way to push new data in nested oject using hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a button and when it's fired a new line data is generated. This is my code

This is my state:

```
const [myData, setMyData] = React.useState({  
  name: "",
  lastname: "",  
  config: [
    { weekday: "mon", hour: [], intervals: [] },
    { weekday: "tue", hour: [], intervals: [] },
    { weekday: "wed", hour: [], intervals: [] },
    { weekday: "thu", hour: [], intervals: [] },
    { weekday: "fri", hour: [], intervals: [] },
    { weekday: "sat", hour: [], intervals: [] },
    { weekday: "sun", hour: [], intervals: [] },
  ],
});
```

This is my "html":

```
{myData.config.map((item, dayKey) => {
  return (
    <div key={dayKey} className={s.day}>                  
      <MyNewLine intervals={item.intervals} />
      
      {/* ...Each click on button a new line is generated*/}
      <Button
        type="primary"          
        onClick={() => {
          addNewLine("intervals", dayKey);
        }}            
      >
        Add new line
      </Button>
    </div>
  )})}
```

My new line component

```
interface IProps {  
  intervals: any[];
}

export function MyNewLine({ intervals }: IProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {intervals.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <div>            
            //... MY DATA            
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
}
```

Here is where the magic happens:
White the `key` I can acess the object that I want. I want to push/join/concat my `newLine` to `intervals[]`. How can I do that?

```
function addNewLine(type: string, key: number) {
  if (type === "intervals") {
    const newLine = myData.config[key].intervals;

    newLine.push({
      start: "",
      end: "",
      minimumAdvanceMinutes: 0,
      minutes: 0,
    });
    
    /*Not works*/
    myData.config[key] = {
      ...myData.config[key],
       [type]: newLine,
    };
  }    
}
```

Maybe with `Object.assign()` I can do it, but change the array by external way it's a extremely bad pratice. So, how can I push a new data to my `intervals[]` using hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config is not an array so you do not access it by key but by index. To push to 2nd element you need to use setMyData:

```
const i = 1
const interval = 'interval'
setMyData(prev => {
  const config = [...prev.config]
  config.[i].intervals.push(interval)
  return {...prev, config}
})
```

Comment: Hmm! Simple and elegant solution, thanks a lot to help me!

Comment: No problem, I would just suggest that when you use hooks for state that you split it as it if data is unrelated, e.g. separate myData into user and config.